# best solution in this sql question

Tags: php, sql

I have following sql query in my header file:

```
// This query is getting points scored by user1, this number changes
// each time user scores more points

$query_points = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE `sender` = user1 AND points= '1'");
$points = mysql_num_rows($query_points);
```

Now if there 3 or more users who are logged in how can i compare their individual points if i want to?

Do i write this sql query 3 times like this:

```
$query_points = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE `sender` = user1 AND points= '1'");
$points1 = mysql_num_rows($query_points);

$query_points = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE `sender` = user2 AND points= '1'");
$points2 = mysql_num_rows($query_points);

$query_points = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE `sender` = user3 AND points= '1'");
$points3 = mysql_num_rows($query_points);
```

Than compare $points1, $points2 and $points3 and post results? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY and LIMIT :

```
  SELECT sender
    FROM quiz
   WHERE points = 1
GROUP BY sender
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 3
```

Which would select the three first senders who have the highest number of points.

By the way, if you only need the number of lines, don't do a `SELECT *` query and use mysql_num_rows. Instead, just do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a group by to return the count for the users in one query.

```
select sender, count(case when points = 1 then 1 end)
from quiz
where sender IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
group by sender
order by count(*)
```

Comment: @ar is this the best solution? Even if i have over 10 or 20 users just use sql query like above? Will this slow down the site?

Comment: @Gurnor: it's a much better solution than what you're trying to do in PHP. If you can do it in SQL, it's generally better.

Comment: If you are going to be running this query frequently on a busy site, then you should consider caching the results to reduce the load on the database.

Comment: actualy i just posted part of the query in order to get complete points. There are two queries to two seperate tables in database. Than at the end i combine both to get points. Like points= query1 result + query2 result. So i should use similar kind of sql for both queries and add the result?